# Calculate move cost based on speed and distance

Tags: javascript, math

I am working on canvas mini game and i want to build a function that calculates cost of moving your ship from point A to point B.

I need 2 things:

- total cost before ship is dispatched
- cost for every tick of move (server loop tick)

Cost is charged every time ship is moved (every time server loop ticks) so total must match sum of all ticks that server made to get it there.

I have simple server loop that moves ship:

```
setInterval(function() {
    ship.move();
}, 10);
```

now the simplified ship code:

```
var rad = (p1, p2) => Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x),
    distance = (p1, p2) => Math.sqrt( (p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p2.y) * (p1.y - p2.y) );

var ship = function() {

    this.x; // current ship x
    this.y; // current ship y
    this.destination; // destination object
    this.total_distance; // total distance before dispatch
    this.remaining_distance; // remaining distance before arrival
    this.speed = 0.5; // ship speed modifier

    this.set_travel = function(target) {
        this.destination = target;
        this.total_distance = distance( { x: this.x, y: this.y }, { x: this.destination.x, y: this.destination.y } );
    };

    this.move = function() {
        this.remaining_distance = distance( { x: this.x, y: this.y }, { x: this.destination.x, y: this.destination.y } );

        var _rad = rad( { x: this.x, y: this.y }, { x: this.destination.x, y: this.destination.y } );

        this.x += Math.cos(rad) * this.speed;
        this.y += Math.sin(rad) * this.speed;
    };

};
```

Now we could introduce fuel cost and add to above code like this:

```
var ship = function() {

    ...
    this.total_fuel_cost; // total fuel cost that player will consume during entire travel

    this.set_travel = function(target) {
        ...
        this.total_fuel_cost = ?
    };

    this.move = function() {
        ...
        player.fuel -= ? // fuel cost every tick that must match total after arrival
    };

};
```

Maybe someone could help solve this problem. Maybe it could be good approach to assume that every 1 distance made cost x fuel, but i dont know if it can be done like this.

----- edit

when ship is created it is instantiated in this way:

```
objects.push(new ship())
```

as i explained in my question, its not acceptable to refuse flying if total is not enough, ship must go as long as it has fuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assembled a little demo using settings that has been provided:

- `move()` loop going on 10 ms interval
- fuel being consumed on the fly
- fuel consumed throughout journey must be equal assumed consumption at the beginning

Logic explanation:

The only variable that is really needed you already have in your logic, it is ship speed.

Your code would look like this:

```
this.move = function() {
    this.remaining_distance = distance( { x: this.x, y: this.y }, { x: this.destination.x, y: this.destination.y } );

    var _rad = rad( { x: this.x, y: this.y }, { x: this.destination.x, y: this.destination.y } );

    this.x += Math.cos(rad) * this.speed;
    this.y += Math.sin(rad) * this.speed;

    player.fuel -= this.speed;
};
```

Lets say that player has `1000` fuel and you need to fly distance of `845`. If we assume that `1 distance === 1 fuel`, we expect that at the end of journey you should have `155` fuel left. Additionally it doesn't matter if you fly fast (say `2`) or slow (say `0.5`), fuel consumption should be the same, as you consume more fuel while flying faster. Above code will do exactly that.

Demo link:
https://jsfiddle.net/7khvxkaa/1/

Fuel cost can be tempered with to deal with smaller numbers for example if assumed that `1 distance === 0.01` fuel you will end up consuming `10` fuel throughout `1000` distance journey. To account above situation this is the only change that needs to be made:

```
player.fuel -= this.speed / 100;
```

Also remember that demo is only for debugging purposes to verify proof of concept, in real environment where you have more variables (for example moving destination or ship acceleration / deceleration) it may be difficult to predict total fuel consume, however logic will still work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

I think you mostly need an explanation about OOP.

Your function ship is not an object; it's (the constructor of) a class.
(Well, that's what other languages would call it.)

To make an object, you do this:

```
var myship = new ship();
```

Here is an example; a bit similar your game. But my main point is for you to look at how you can use an object.  As you can see, the property myship.fuel keeps track of the fuel; it will refuse to move if a trip requires more fuel than it has.

Calculations you can handle yourself.  Just look at "what properties do I have?"  "What do I need?", ...

```
<script>
// constructor 
function Ship(elementId) {
  // properties
  this.elm = document.getElementById(elementId);
  this.x = 0;                      // current ship x
  this.y = 0;                      // current ship y
  this.fuel = 300;
  this.fuelprice = 0.2;            // moving 1 pixel costs 0.2 fuel 
  this.destination = {x:0, y:0};   // destination object

  // static function, doesn't interact with any property, just takes parameters ans returns something
  this.distance = function(p1, p2) {
    return Math.sqrt( (p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p2.y) * (p1.y - p2.y) ); // Pythagoras
  }
  this.rad = function(p1, p2) {
    return Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);
  }

  // method.  this is a function bound to an object.  Whomever calls this function will be affected.
  // in this case myship will be moved, but there could be many boats in the game; many buttons that each move 1 boat, ...
  this.moveTo = function(to) {
    var from = {x: this.x, y: this.y};
    var totalDistance = this.distance(from, to);
    // see if there is enougn fuel
    var fuelNeeded = this.fuelprice * totalDistance;
    if(this.fuel >= fuelNeeded) {
      display(
        '<h3>This trip</h3>'+
        'total distance: ' + totalDistance + '<br/>'+
        'fuel at start: ' + this.fuel +'<br/>'+
        'fuel needed: ' + fuelNeeded +'<br/>'
      );
      this.moveStep(to, 10, 10);
      // 
      this.fuel -= fuelNeeded;
    }
    else {
      display(
        '<h3>Not enough fuel</h3>'+
        'fuel at start: ' + this.fuel +'<br/>'+
        'fuel needed: ' + fuelNeeded +'<br/>'
      );
    }
  }

  // function that calls itself, until stepsLeft = 0
  this.moveStep = function(to, steps, stepsLeft) {
    var self = this;  // within a setTimeout the "this" changes its meaning.  So I make a copy.
    var x = to.x + (this.x - to.x) * (stepsLeft / steps);
    var y = to.y + (this.y - to.y) * (stepsLeft / steps);
    if(stepsLeft > 0) {
      this.elm.style.left = x;
      this.elm.style.top = y;
      setTimeout(function() { self.moveStep(to, steps, stepsLeft - 1) }, 100);
    }
    else {
      // animation is finished, so the "to" situation becomes the new x and y
      this.x = to.x;
      this.y = to.y;
    }
  }
}

// function that uses the myship object
function submitMove() {
  myship.moveTo({
    x: Number(document.getElementById('x').value), 
    y: Number(document.getElementById('y').value)
  });
}

// just to display messages to screen
function display(message) {
  document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = message;
}

// now this is our object: myship
var myship;

// when the page is loaded we can make myship a Ship object
window.onload = function() {
  myship = new Ship('boat');
}

</script>
<style>
#sea {
  position: relative;
  background: #2040f0;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
#boat {
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
<div id="sea">
  <img id="boat" src="http://icons.veryicon.com/32/Leisure/Summer%20Holiday/sailing%20boat.png" />
</div>
<hr/>
<input id="x" placeholder="X" value="200">
<input id="y" placeholder="X" value="40">
<input type="button" value="GO" onclick="submitMove()">
<div id="display"></display>
```

Comment: your conclusion is a little bit to hasty, no one here has issues with OOP, just by looking at the code it gets obvious that somewhere in my code ship is instantiated from the constructor i presented. Your solution is very bad, i specifically explained that trip is starting even if total is bigger then your current state of fuel, it just wont get to the end, but calculation must be made on the fly. Also game using divs? i think you mostly need explanation on what technology to use while building any game.

Comment: this answer doesn't focus at all on solving problem, content of this answer is unrelated to the question asked.